# Can I use DateField with timestamp value in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I have timestamp(String) value.
Can I use DateField with timestamp?

```
<DateField source="createdAt" showTime /> // createAt: timeStamp(String)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast your timestamp to an integer, e.g. using a custom component:

```js
const DateFieldForTimestamp = props => {
    const recordWithTimestampAsInteger = {
        [props.source]: parseInt(props.record[props.source], 10)
    };
    return <DataField {...props} record={recordWithTimestampAsInteger} />
}
```

Comment: DataField should be DateField